# JQuery Validate: Validating a hidden form (possible bug)

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using the [JQuery Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to handle form validation.

The problem I am having is that when a form is hidden, the validation plugin ignores the fields that need to be validated and jumps straight to submitting the form.

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Qg5WQ/**

I have had a look through the plugin's [options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#source) and googled this issue but I cannot find anything that specifies why fields within a hidden form are ignored.

It is worth noting that if there are two forms on a page, where one is hidden and one is displayed, that both forms are successfully validated if both forms use the same validation method. However, if you call two seperate validation methods then the fields within the hidden form are still ignored.

***Validating two forms using the same validation function: http://jsfiddle.net/Qg5WQ/1/***

Validating two forms using different validation functions: http://jsfiddle.net/Qg5WQ/2/

Does anyone know if this is a bug or is there a specific way to validate hidden forms?

Comment: i am facing the same issues, so i am making my own code to validate the form. (when i am in .aspx webform)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/Qg5WQ/3/

I added the `ignore` : `hidden` option to the `validate` call.

```
$("form").validate({
  ignore: 'hidden',
  rules: {
    "first": "required"
  },
  invalidHandler: function() {
    alert("error");   
  },
  submitHandler: function( form ) {
    alert("no error");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that oddly does work. I seem to be able to add anything into the ignore field and it works. I guess this must force it to iterate through the fields which makes me think that this must be a bug. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MyHeadHurts - Yes, I noticed that, very strange, but good it works anyway=)

Comment: Just a quick note that the reason this works is because you're missing the colon from the front of **:hidden**. You're essentially telling it to ignore any html **<hidden>** tags that may exist rather than telling it to ignore inputs of type hidden.

Answer (score 7):

If you check out the `ignore` option on the [documentation page](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), it says that the default value is `:hidden`. This obviously means that if you don't specify the `ignore` option explicitly, the validation will ignore hidden inputs.

Simply define the `ignore` option (it can be left blank) and it should fix the problem.

```
$("form").validate({
  ignore: '',
  rules: {"hidden_field": {required:true}}
});
```

Comment: +1 - thanks, that explains why adding anything into ignore still worked